# MapKit runtime error in mapView(_:didAdd:) with clustering

Tags: swift, mapkit, xcode9.3

I have an unexpected error when implementing `MKMapViewDelegate`'s method `mapView(_:didAdd:)`. It is happening since Xcode 9.3 and was not happening with Xcode 9.2. When using clustering, I get a runtime error when using `views` array.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    if let view = views.first { // Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
        print(type(of: view))
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the `views` array does not contain only `MKAnnotationView` instances as expected. Here is what `views` contains on crash.

[image]

I see that there is an `MKClusterAnnotation` instance inside. If this is true I get the error, but **why** is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

This is easily reproductible by implementing the method on the sample from [WWDC 2017 - Session 237 What's New in MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem.  If you implement clustering and supply a mapView(_:didAdd:) method, you will crash - This is definitely an Apply framework bug.  The issue is easily reproducible in iOS 11.3, but fortunately has been corrected in iOS 11.4.